# average is higher than percentile 90 ?...

Tags: statistics

I have a few hundreds of results from a test im running, and with a utility I have that analyzes these results I can see that the Average result value is higher than the percentile 90th value...
This seems a little weird to me, since I know that most of the results recorder (exactly 89%) are below the percentile 90 value, therefore i figure this means that the 10% of the results above the percentile 90 value are probably very far from the median.

What else can this tell me about my results ?

Details on the results : average = 550, percentile 90 = 540.
A valid results could be anything from 1 up to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I throw $2$ dice and I set $X=36$ if I throw a double $6$ and $X=0$ otherwise.  Then the average result is $1$ because there's a $\frac 1{36}$ chance of scoring $36$ and a $\frac{35}{36}$ chance of scoring $0$.  But over $97$% of your results are less than $1$.

Your example here is a less extreme version of this.  You have a small chance of getting a very high number, which is distorting the average, but because the really high ones happen less than $10$% of the time it's not changing your $90$th percentile.

From your data there's not very much else you can say.  You could have $90$% of your data at $0$ and $10$% at $5500$. Or you could have $90$% of your data at $539$ and $10$% at $649$ which is a bit less extreme.   Or all sorts of things in between.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think you gave me a better view on what's happening... :)

Comment: My advice would be to draw a good old fashioned bar chart. (Your utility should be able to handle this) Then you can get a feel for what's going on.